# How does a C library call kernel system calls

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I know in Unix-like systems c librarys such as glibc acts as an intermediary between the kernel and the userland. So for example when implementing `malloc()` how does glibc invoke system calls of the linux kernel does it use assembly?

Comment: glibc is open source. If you are interested in how it does something you can just look at it.

Comment: Might be helpful http://linuxseekernel.blogspot.ie/2014/07/adding-system-call-in-x86-qemu.html

Answer (score 3):

In Linux x86 syscalls (system calls) are made by calling interrupt `0x80`. In assembly it is done with:

```
int $0x80
```

The choice of syscall is done by passing information to the CPU registers. `malloc` itself is not a syscall, but `malloc` algorithm usually uses `sbrk` or `mmap` syscalls (`brk` syscall for `sbrk`).

For more information on Linux x86 syscalls, you can read this [document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/syscall/syscall86.html).

**EDIT:** as mentioned by Jester in the comments, Intel x86 processors (after Pentium IV) now support `systenter`/`sysexit` instructions that don't have the `int` overhead and on these processors these instructions are used by Linux for syscalls.

Comment: The OP didn't say ia32 or x86_64. it might be helpful to note that on x86-64 the preferred method is via `syscall` instruction (although int 0x80 is retained for backwards compatibility but has some extra overhead). Information on x86_64 System V ABI can be found here: http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf

Comment: `int $0x80` isn't the preferred method in 32 bit either, since quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

Example of calling exit(0) syscall on 0x86 architecture.

```
movl $1, %eax   #$1=number of exit syscall. 
movl $0, %ebx   #$0=First argument of exit syscall
int 0x80        #call the software interrupt
```

Every syscall has been given a number that can be found in /usr/include/asm/unistd.h. In the above example exit syscall has number 1.
Then you set the argument required for the syscall. After that you call software interrupt int 0x80.

So for malloc, it will internally call brk or mmap and then it will set the required arguments and then will call int0x80.

Comment: How control flow continues after int 0x80? Means after that what code and how it gets executed?